# Change Category Images from .png to .jpg

Tags: category, image

I have several hundreds of category Images containing a .png extension. But I want to convert that images to .jpg (outside of Magento and not part of that question) and then reupload them to **media/catalog/category** and tell Magento to use the new .jpg extension for all .png Category Images. Including Thumbnail Image and Image field.

I found the quite similar Question [Migrating All Product Images in Magento from PNGs to JPEGs](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/migrating-all-product-images-in-magento-from-pngs-to-jpegs) but the difference is that I want to change Category Images and not Product Images.

Can someone tell me how to change that script or a different approach, please? Updating all Categories in the backend manually would take to much time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a one time change you may wish to consider taking a SQL approach. This will be quicker, and, if you backup your database before hand, you can do this safely.

Your images for the categories are held in catalog_category_entity_varchar table however you did not say whether these are the main images or the thumbnails. Therefore have a quick search of the table to find out:

```
SELECT * FROM  `catalog_category_entity_varchar` WHERE  `value` LIKE  '%.png%';
```

This should return images that you know. Look at the value for attribute_id. This could be something like '45'.

Now you want to run an update, replacing xx with your attribute_id:

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_entity_varchar` SET `value` = REPLACE(`value`, '.png', '.jpg') WHERE `attribute_id`=xx;
```

If you are not happy with updating the database directly in a few minutes you could write a Magento module, iterate on the categories and update the image accordingly. However, for a one off the sql approach should work out nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted the mySQL solution as it seems to be the easier one. But we have changed the code of that script in the meantime so I thought why not add this as well.

```
  <?php

require('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$storeId = 0;
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);

$category = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/category' );

$tree = $category->getTreeModel ();

$tree->load();
$ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();

    foreach ($ids as $id) {

        $pk = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

        $pk->load($id);

        #print_r($pk->getImageUrl()."<br>");

        $pk->setImage(str_ireplace('.png', '.jpg', $pk->getImage()));
        $pk->setThumbnail(str_ireplace('.png', '.jpg', $pk->getThumbnail()));
        $pk->setImageUrl(str_ireplace('.png', '.jpg', $pk->getImageUrl()));
        $pk->save();
        #print_r($pk->getImage()."<br>");

    }
```